# Return in recursive function PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel, return, echo

im working with laravel and php, im doing a recursive function, the problem is that the `return` value of the function doesnt work just work `echo`.

The code is the this.

```
public function getSitioPadre($id){
    $padre =  md_sitio_espacios::where([['SITIO_ESPACIOS_ID','=',$id]])->get()->toArray();       
    if($padre[0]["PADRE"] == 0){
        return $padre[0]["SITIO_ESPACIOS_ID"];
    }else{
        $this->getSitioPadre($padre[0]["PADRE"]);
    }
}
```

When i call this function like :

```
echo $this->getSitioPadre(54);
```

returns nothing,

If in the function i use : `echo $padre[0]["SITIO_ESPACIOS_ID"]`instead of `return` it works.

Let me know what can i do, thank you.

Comment: Seem like you need to `return $this->getSitioPadre($padre[0]["PADRE"]);`

Comment: @AlonEitan you right thats the error, i dint think about it thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to return anything in your else clause.

```
public function getSitioPadre($id){
    $padre =  md_sitio_espacios::where([['SITIO_ESPACIOS_ID','=',$id]])->get()->toArray();       
    if($padre[0]["PADRE"] == 0){
        return $padre[0]["SITIO_ESPACIOS_ID"];
    }else{
        return $this->getSitioPadre($padre[0]["PADRE"]); // should work better
    }
}
```